# Retrieve lists from Controller to View using Entity Framework

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4

I am trying to retrieve the list of datas in view from controller in ASP.Net .
I have two models

```
public class TableGroupModel
{
    public int groupId { get; set; }
    public string groupName { get; set; }
    public string color { get; set; }
    public bool is_active { get; set; }
    public int groupPosition { get; set; }
}
```

and another model

```
  public class TableModel
     {
         public int tableId { get; set; }
         public string  tableName { get; set; }
         public bool isReserved { get; set; }
         public int seats { get; set; }
         public string tableType { get; set; }
         //added from cafe_table_group

         List<Models.TableGroupModel> group { get; set; }
     }
```

My controller is

```
  public ActionResult Index()
         {
             using(entity_framework.dbEntities e=new entity_framework.dbEntities())
             {

                 var tables = (from c in e.cafe_table
                              join d in e.cafe_table_group on c.cafe_table_group_id equals d.cafe_table_group_id
                              orderby c.cafe_table_group_id
                              select new
                              {
                                  c.cafe_table_id,
                                 c.table_name,
                                  c.seats,
                                   c.is_reserved,
                                  d.cafe_table_group_name,
                                d.color
                              }).ToList();
                 return View(tables);
             }
         }
```

Now how can I use data list in view?

Comment: Not clear what you want. Do you want to create a table in view? If so better you create another class (view model) with props as in your select statement in controller. And create a strongly typed view using that model.

Comment: First, if you've properly configured your models you shouldn't need the join - you can simply access the navigation properties (one of the strengths of EF). To use your data in a view, you could do it manually or scaffold it with a `List` type since it is a collection. See [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/older-versions-1/models-data/displaying-a-table-of-database-data-cs)

Comment: I want to send that selected fields through TableModel to the view. I hadn't use ang relationships between columns of any table. Because of that I am unable to use relationships now.

Comment: `var table` is a dynamic type so learn how to use that(its better to put into known class). on a side note your classes you included have nothing to do with `cafe_table` and `cafe_table_group` which were included in the question.

Comment: @Seabizkit sorry to say that I didn't get you. I just wanted to show retrieved datas in View portion.Could  you please suggest me how can I do that?

Comment: where you have `select new` its should say something like`select new CustomObj() { TableId = cafe_table_id,...other properties }` then you know that the view is expecting CustomObj so you can then code accordingly, atm you have dynamic being expected by the view which is kinda pointless to code against as its unknown and so can not give you any sugar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create ViewModel class and select using that class like this:

```
     select new MyViewModel
        {
          TableId=   c.cafe_table_id,
          TableName= c.table_name,
          Seats=     c.seats,
          IsReserved=c.is_reserved,
          GroupName= d.cafe_table_group_name,
          Color= d.color
          }).ToList();
```

In your view(.cshtml file) in first line specify your viewModel like this:

```
@model MyViewModel
```

and start using it like this for example:

```
  <div> @Model.IsReserved </div>
```

Comment: Sir is it possible to use all the properties of TableGroupModel in TableModel? So that I needn't repeat the same properties